# Power function definition

Tags: functions

Is

$$y=x^4+3$$

a power function? I know the format for a power function is $ax^b$, but does adding three make it not one?

Comment: What's nice about an exponential function is that it satisfies $f(x + y) = f(x)f(y)$, no matter the base ("the addition of inputs is the multiplication of outputs"). Does yours satisfy this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's a power function with a vertical translation